# Wordpress templates to HTMl + CSS

Tags: html, xhtml, css

I have a wordpress template and in that there are many PHP files and CSS files. I just want to know how can i convert every php file into HTML file so that i can check them in the browser and i want to change wherever  i feel necessary.

Comment: Why would you want this? Why not select the theme, and test it in Wordpress itself?

Answer (score 1):

You need to render them with a machine that has PHP with Wordpress installed, and you could then save them as HTML from there.

The quickest way to do that would be to use [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) (assuming that you are on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on what @Blowski said. Here is a  useful article which will help you walk through the right steps to installing XAMPP on your machine. [Using XAMPP For Local Theme Dev.](http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/web-development-tutorials/using-xampp-for-local-wordpress-theme-development/)